# C# Migrations With Multiple Databases

Tags: c#, migration, entity-framework-migrations

Does one single context accep two different databases with migrations?

I'm trying to use two different databases: one official server and one just for tests - with same structures. However if I update one of them I cant update ('update-database') the other one...

Comment: Sure, just change the connection string or script out the migration. We prefer migrations for our DEV and UAT environments, but DBA requires a script for PROD. Web.config transforms make it pretty easy.

Comment: See Fabio's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34605117/entity-framework-and-different-environments-dev-production)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Entity Framework, you'll need 2 different db contexts... one for each database.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm using EF6. Ok, so basically if I have two diff contexts, they will run (through 'update-dabase' command) simultaneously in each db? I mean the updates...

Comment: Both have the same structure and data...  Have you considered using a database trigger?  When a row gets entered into your official table, have an after insert trigger fire to update your test environment.

Comment: Nah, I think this is not a good ideia, because my official db is huge. My main ideia is keep both updated (columns and tables, not necessarily data) so I can test on the test db and then run command to update de main db...

Answer (score 0):

You have two Db for An Application Context , There are two ways for doing that :

1 - you can have two connection strings once for test and another for official DB

2 - Or you can downgrading your DB or Upgrading migration with Update-Database -TargetMigration: but your up and down method should be precise .