# ASP.NET MVC network-related or instance-specific error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am getting this error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26
>   - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)'

When I try to run my ASP.NET MVC project. Opening it for the first time on this PC.(I try to register a user and the database doesn't get created and I get the error above.) The database should get created the first time I hit the database PS: It's a code first project
I thought I know how to fix it until now.
The project runs on my other PC but on this not.
So I thought I'll go  and change the connection string to

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="foo"
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
         connectionString="Data Source=localhost"/> 
</connectionStrings>
```

(just change the `Data Source=` to `localhost`)
The constructor in my DbContext is

```
public EventManagerDbContext() : base("foo")
        {

        }
```

Still I can't run my project.
PS: I am able to connect to my database using the SQL Server Management Studio, but not from the project. Why is that?
I realised that the problem was that my connection string was placed in the Data Access Layer. But it has to be in the ASP.NET MVC application right? Would like some clarification.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework DbContext constructor with connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24308360/entity-framework-dbcontext-constructor-with-connection-string)

Comment: @Munzer it has nothing to do with that...

Answer (score 0):

Provide a complete details to your connectionstring like this:

```
<add name="foo" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS2014;Initial Catalog=NameOfYourDB;
Integrated Security=True;" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I suppose that your localhost is `.\SQLEXPRESS2014` is your local machine server name.

To get the full server name on your part, connect to server, under Server Name, choose Browse for more option, then select Network Servers tab, and it will list your qualified server name:

[image]